# how to insert string into sql query?

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, c

below is part of my code,

```
 ...
 char hashvalue[]="somehash"; // or i can use std::string

 SQLCHAR* query = (SQLCHAR*)"SELECT username FROM users WHERE hash = ..." ;
 SQLExecDirectA( hStmt, query, SQL_NTS );
 ...
```

In the code above I have no idea how to insert into query hashvalue to execute my query like this:

```
 SQLCHAR* query = (SQLCHAR*)"SELECT username FROM users WHERE hash = "somehash"" ;
```

I 'm very new to sql, thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Use `std::string` and bask in the glory of overloaded operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::string`

```
std::string query_string = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE hash = ";
query_string += hashvalue;
SQLExecDirectA(hStmt, query_string.c_str(), SQL_NTS);
```

Another method:

```
char query_buffer[1024];
snprintf(query_buffer,
         "SELECT username FROM users WHERE hash = %s",
         hashValue);
SQLExecDirectA(hStmt, query_buffer, SQL_NTS);
```

Basically, your question is how to create a formatted string and has nothing to do with SQL.